# Inheriting Multiple Classes From Imported Libraries (Java - Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have a class that needs to inherit from two other classes. 
I need my portfoioActivity class to extend the Fragment class and the AppCompatActivity class for all the functions to work. I thought about using interfaces, but because the classes are being imported through libraries, I wasn't sure where to go from there. I also tried aggregation but that didn't work either, but then again, it's possible I did it incorrectly as I'm new to Java.

```
public class portfolioActivity  {

    ListView portfolioList;
    String[] stockTicker={"AAPL", "GOOG", "MSFT"};
    double[] stockPrice={138.96, 830.63, 64.01};
    int[] shares={5, 2, 10};
    double[] percentChange={0.59, 0.55, 1.43};

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        getActivity().setTitle("Portfolio");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.portfolio_layout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.portfolio_layout);

        portfolioList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.portfolioListView);

        //ADAPTER
        ListAdapter adapter = new portfolioListAdapter(this, stockTicker, stockPrice, shares, percentChange);
        portfolioList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class `portfolioActivity` isn't extending any classes or implementing any interfaces. So, I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Also, classes can only extend a single class, they cannot extend multiple classes. They can, however, implement multiple interfaces.

Comment: I removed the extending classes before uploading the code, sorry about that. In regards to interfaces, I'm not making these classes myself so I'm not sure how I would go about turning them into interfaces before implementing them.

Comment: You cannot turn classes into interfaces. If these classes you need to extend are indeed classes, then the developers of the API didn't intend on you to do what you're trying to do. Why can't you create two separate classes?

Comment: I tried removing my onCreate() function and placing it in its own class called portfolioCreator (along with the variables up top). I need both classes to be called in succession for my page to fully load. As of right now, only the portfolioActivity class is being called. I'll try to continue and tweak my code, but any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I tried calling my portfolioCreator after my portfolioActivity, but it completely covers up my portfolioActivity.
`fragment = new portfolioActivity();
                intent = new Intent(this, portfolioCreator.class);`